# TypeError at /users/sigup create_user() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

Tags: python, django

My models has username, birthdate, language, curreny, etc...

i make guest need to fill there username, email, password (required), and birthdate(optional) when they try to sign up. but error occur.

> TypeError at /users/sigup
>   create_user() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

**models.py**

```
username = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, unique=True)
language = models.CharField(
    choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, max_length=2, blank=True, default=LANGUAGE_KOREAN)
currency = models.CharField(
    choices=CURRENCY_CHOICES, max_length=2, blank=True, default=CURRENCY_KOREA)
birthdate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
login_method = models.CharField(
    max_length=50, choices=LOGIN_CHOICES, default=LOGIN_EMAIL)
```

**forms.py**

```
def save(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
    email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
    password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
    birthdate = self.cleaned_data.get("birthdate")
    user = models.User.objects.create_user(
        username, email, password, birthdate)
    user.save()
```

**views.py**

```
   class SignUpView(FormView):
        template_name = "users/signup.html"
        form_class = forms.SignUpForm
        success_url = reverse_lazy("cores:home")

        def form_valid(self, form):
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            birthdate = self.cleaned_data.get("birthdate")
            user = authenticate(self.request, email=email, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(self.request, user)
            return super().form_valid(form)
```

want to the guest login with email and password, but how can I acheive it?

Comment: Show the proper content of `models.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Birthday should be passed as keyword argument:

```
user = models.User.objects.create_user(username, email, password, birthdate=birthdate)
```

Since [`create_user()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) accepts only username, email, password as positional arguments. Any other additional parameters should be keyword arguments.